# Valores iniciais na função nls no R

Tags: r, regressão

Olá, tenho o seguinte código em R

```
temp<-c(10,12,14,15,17,20,22,23,25,26,28,29,30)
taxa<-c(2,4.5,6.1,7.0,11,16,19,21,22,11,2,0.1,0.001)
taxa<-taxa/9
plot(temp,taxa)
df<- data.frame(temp,taxa)
x<- seq(1,45,length=100)
library(nlsMicrobio)
preview(taxa~(exp(p*temp)-exp(p*TL-(TL-temp)/delta)+z),data=df, start=list (p=0.2, TL=30, delta=4.9,z=-0.5))
fit<- nls (taxa~exp(p*temp)-exp(p*TL-(TL-temp)/delta)+z,data=df, 
                start=list (p=0.2, TL=30, delta=4.9,z=-0.5),control=nls.control(maxiter = 1000))
summary(fit)
```

Ao executar fit está ocorrendo o seguinte erro:

```
Error in nls(taxa ~ exp(p * temp) - exp(p * TL - (TL - temp)/delta) +  : 
  fator de passos 0.000488281 reduzido abaixo de 'minFactor' de 0.000976562
```

Alguém poderia me auxiliar com esse errro? Obrigado.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A função `nls` é utilizada para fazer uma regressão não-linear. Ela utiliza processos iterativos para obter as estimativas dos parâmetros do teu modelo. Em teoria estes processos iterativos vão pouco a pouco se aproximando do valor real do parâmetro da função que melhor se ajusta aos teus dados.

O problema com regressões não-lineares é que elas podem, em casos extremos, não ter solução. Isto é, pode ser que o algoritmo que esteja procurando as estimativas para os parâmetros do teu modelo não convirja nunca, principalmente se o modelo a ser ajustado aos dados estiver mal especificado. Para evitar isto, é necessário informar critérios de parada para o algoritmo. O teu código tem um deles, chamado `maxiter = 1000`. Ele quer dizer que, se a função `nls` não convergir em 1.000 iterações, o algoritmo deve parar.

O erro ocorrido no teu exemplo remete a outro critério de parada, chamado `minFactor`. Ele diz quão pequeno é o passo utilizado para atingir a convergência dos parâmetros (mais informações [neste link](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/nls.control.html)). Por padrão, a função `nls` utiliza um passo igual a 1/1024 (ou seja, (1/2)^10).

Assim, basta brincar com os valores de `maxiter` e `minFactor`, dentro de `nls.control`, para fazer com que o teu algoritmo convirja. Veja abaixo a minha sugestão:

```
fit <- nls (taxa~exp(p*temp)-exp(p*TL-(TL-temp)/delta)+z,data=df, 
  start=list (p=0.2, TL=30, delta=4.9,z=-0.5), 
  control=nls.control(maxiter = 10000, minFactor=(1/2)^30))

summary(fit)

Formula: taxa ~ exp(p * temp) - exp(p * TL - (TL - temp)/delta) + z

Parameters:
      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
p      0.09981    0.51807   0.193 0.851505    
TL    31.04889    5.73290   5.416 0.000424 ***
delta  6.33825   18.63529   0.340 0.741569    
z     -1.73670    7.20604  -0.241 0.814952    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4274 on 9 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 1057 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 9.783e-06
```

Eu diminuí o `minFactor`para (1/2)^30 e aumentei o número máximo de iterações para 10.000. Perceba que o algoritmo precisou de 1057 iterações para convergir, mais do que as 1.000 definidas originalmente.

Note, inclusive, que visualmente o ajuste ficou bastante razoável. Perceba como a curva predita se aproxima muito bem dos dados originais:

```
plot(temp, taxa)
lines(temp, predict(fit, temp))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sua sugestões me auxiliaram e muito. Problema resolvido. Obrigado.

Comment: Considere aceitar a [resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta) já que ela foi útil para você resolver o seu problema.